# Problems installing angular 2 packages using npm in VS2015 Update 2

Tags: angularjs, node.js, visual-studio-2015, npm, asp.net-core

I am attempting to use the latest angular2 quickstart files with a new empty ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web Application.

VS2015 Update 2 - w/ Core 1.0 RC2 installed

**Steps to reproduce:**
Create a new project using ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) - Empty Template

Add the [4 angular quick-start files](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) to your root directory, NOT Hitting save on package.json until the other 3 are added and saved.

Finally, hit save on package.json and npm will start installing all of the packages. However, at the end I see Dependencies - not installed, npm - not installed. I can't figure out what could be causing this. It has to be a VS2015 / npm bug because if I use VSCode and npm from command line everything installs perfectly with this package.json file.

Comment: Try `npm install` at the root directory, it might be just be a bug in 
VS as I have the same issue -- however my packages are in fact there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the Web Tools for ASP.NET Core RC2, which was discovered after RC2 was shipped. It's only that the "- not installed" UI is showing up incorrectly. The packages are successfully installed.

I'm not sure what is causing it yet, but we are aware of the issue and will try to fix this in a future release of the Web Tools.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was just saying it and everything was actually installed correctly because when searching through the dependency tree I didn't see anything with the yellow ! sign.

Comment: @JoeDavis any idea when this might happen? any links to docs or timeline? We're in Update 3 and 4 months later and no fix yet